# document.ExecCommand insertHTML inserts span and weird behaviour in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, execcommand, inserthtml

When trying to use insertHTML

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, `<b id="searchId${numberID}" style="background-color: ${color};" >${text}</b>`
```

Works fine in any browser except Safari.

Example: Trying to insert the html if the a tag has "Passage" word. However only in Safari, if the "Passage" word is either at the end of the order of tags, or has a space and other text, inserts something like this

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, `<span style="background-color: ${color};" >${text}</span>`
```

--------------- Examples

> Passage1 | OtherTag = Works
>
> Passage 1 | OtherTag = Doesn't work
>
> OtherTag | Passage1 = Doesn't work

This feature is used to highlight text written in a searchbar across a lot of displayed documents, and has an anchor feature to travel across all the results, to it's a need to have the ID's.

Works in IE, Firefox, Mozilla, Chrome and Opera.
Not working in Safari.

More accurate examples :

Search word "Passage"

In all browsers except Safari

```
<div class="col-8 px-0">
  <p class="badge badge-document">
    <b id="searchId1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 226, 183);">
      Passage
    </b>
   1
  </p>
</div>
```

In safari (Only if there is a space and another text (Passage1 works, Passage 1 doesnt work, and also usually I have 2-3 tags per document, if (in this scenario) Passage is the last one (Tag 1 - Tag 2 - Passage1/Passage 1) adds this span, if it's first or in the middle, adds the b as all the other browsers.

```
<div class="col-8 px-0">
 <p class="badge badge-document">
  <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 226, 183);">
      Passage
  </span>
   1
 </p>
</div>
```

Safari

> Passage1 + not last tag = adds the b block
>
> Passage 1 + not last tag = adds the span block without ID
>
> Passage1 + last tag = adds the span block without ID
>
> Passage 1 + last tag = adds the span block without ID

```js
function insertHTML(text) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
    while (window.find(text)) {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<b id="searchId1"     style="background-color: red" >Passage</b>');        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
      document.designMode = "off";
  }
 }
```

```html
<input id="inputSearch" type="search" placeholder="Search" value="Passage">
 
 <button id="button" type="search" onClick="insertHTML(inputSearch.value)"> Search</button>


<p>Passage 1</p>
<p>Tag 2</p>
<p>Tag 3</p>
```

EDIT: Found solution here : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033737/inserthtml-unwraps-div-while-inserting-when-selection-is-inside-a-node)
TLDR: Had to envelope the insertable element in a parent div.

Comment: Can you make a working example that shows the problem?

Comment: Added more examples :) !

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page in the editor) to make a runnable example here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Just curious; why not use `innerHTML += whatever`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey done ! :)
Could'nt make it work with innerHTML, with insertHTML seems to work fine in all browsers except safari

Comment: FYI, it's not changing the background color to red in Chrome either because the code is missing the ending quote on the id attribute: `<b id="searchId1     style="b...` should be `<b id="searchId1"     style="b...`. I see that in the code that's not in the snippet so I figure it's a typo.

Comment: Yes it was a typo i made when doing the runnable example, thanks for telling :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insertHTML unwraps div while inserting when selection is inside a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033737/inserthtml-unwraps-div-while-inserting-when-selection-is-inside-a-node)